# GitLab- List of reviewer

Tags: gitlab, merge-request

I am new to GitLab. I want to create a list of reviewers for my project. How do I can create it? I just want to assign a reviewer from my group to one merge-request.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilites regarding the [Merge Request Approvals](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/merge_request_approvals.html) documentation:

> - Enforcing review of all code that gets merged into a repository.
> - Specifying reviewers for a given proposed code change, as well as a minimum number of reviewers, through [Approval rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/merge_request_approvals.html#approval-rules).
> - Specifying categories of reviewers, such as backend, frontend, quality assurance, database, and so on, for all proposed code changes.
> - Designating [Code Owners as eligible approvers](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/merge_request_approvals.html#code-owners-as-eligible-approvers), determined by the files changed in a merge request.

If you want to organize your developers, you can also use a [group](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/), for example.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, for gitlab.com SaaS Ultimate only, you also have the alternative of using, with [GitLab 15.10](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/03/22/gitlab-15-10-released/#suggested-reviewers-generally-available) (March 2023):

> ### Suggested Reviewers generally available
>
> Since release in closed beta, Suggested Reviewers has been enabled in over 1,000 projects and suggested over 200,000 reviewers. We’ve also made the service more reliable and are now making it generally available to all Ultimate customers.
>
> Deciding the right person to [review your merge request](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/reviews/) isn’t always straightforward or obvious. Choosing the wrong reviewer can cause delays, low quality reviews, back and forth reassigning reviewers, or even no review at all.
>
> Now, GitLab can recommend a reviewer with [Suggested Reviewers](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/reviews/#suggested-reviewers).
> Using the changes in a merge request and a project’s contribution graph, machine learning powered suggestions appear in the [reviewer dropdown](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/getting_started.html#reviewer) in the merge request sidebar.
> Suggested Reviewers is our first—[of many](/blog/2023/03/16/what-the-ml-ai/)—fully available ML feature at GitLab.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_10/create-code-review-suggested-reviewers.png -- Suggested Reviewers generally available]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/reviews/#suggested-reviewers) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/modelops/applied-ml/review-recommender/-/epics/3).